# No debuggable processes in Logcat and debug window

Tags: android, android-studio

I got so confused by android studio.it can't identify my device.
like this
[image]

the app is build in debug mode.
[image]

besides, if I kill the adb server and restart the adb, it can identify the device and the process, the after a while, if I kill the app, and reopen it, the android studio cannot identify it again...

No other processes occupy adb process.I even reinstalled my Android Studio, but still not work.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstall the platform-tools in android studio->sdk manager. And then the problem was solved.

Comment: Thank you @Kirin_CN. Your reinstalling platform-tools fixed the same issue. However, the logcat still seems some-kind unstable.